# When I upgraded to targetSdkVersion 33 according to Google Play's policy, Facebook Deferred Deeplink stopped working properly

Tags: android, android-deep-link, facebook-sdk-4.x

When I upgraded to targetSdkVersion 33 according to Google Play's policy, Facebook Deferred Deeplink stopped working properly. Before that, everything was working fine when targetSdkVersion was 32.

Translation:
Through the test on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/, I can receive messages in the Facebook app. However, I am unable to receive delayed links when I install and open the app.